Generic TypeVar solution for class that produces another class that contains the original class
I'm trying to come up with a generic TypeVar solution to avoid having to create an ever expanding Uniontype annotation. Here's a somewhat contrived MRE of what I have currently:
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union

class CreatedDetails:
    def __init__(self, creator: Union[Creator1, Creator2], new: bool) -> None:
        self.creator = creator
        self.new = new

class Creator1:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name = "creator1"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=True)

class Creator2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name = "creator2"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=False)

creator1 = Creator1()
created = creator1.create()
created.creator.name

This plays nice and my type checker recognises everything:

However, this relies on me adding new Creator classes to the Ùnion type annotation.
I've tried using a generic TypeVar:
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar

CreatorRecord = TypeVar("CreatorRecord")

class CreatedDetails:
    def __init__(self, creator: CreatorRecord, new: bool) -> None:
        self.creator = creator
        self.new = new

class Creator:
    pass

class Creator1(Creator):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = "foo"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=True)

class Creator2(Creator):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bar = "bar"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=False)

creator1 = Creator1()
created = creator1.create()
created.creator.foo
created.new

However, the type checker doesn't fully recognise this:

Where am I going wrong?

CreatedDetails itself has to be generic. If all the type checker knows is that created is an instance of CreatedDetails, that's not enough to tell the specific type of creator that created it. But with the right annotations, a type of CreatedDetails[Creator1] would give that information.
You've made a generic constructor, but what you really need is a generic class:
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
Creator = TypeVar("Creator")

class CreatedDetails(Generic[Creator]):
    creator: Creator
    new: bool
    def __init__(self, creator: Creator, new: bool) -> None:
        self.creator = creator
        self.new = new

class Creator1:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = "foo"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails['Creator1']:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=True)

class Creator2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bar = "bar"

    def create(self) -> CreatedDetails['Creator2']:
        return CreatedDetails(creator=self, new=False)


If you're using a recent enough version of Python (>= 3.11), you can use typing.Self to avoid the awkward return annotation on the create methods. It removes the need for a quoted forwards reference, and doesn't require repeating the class name. It even works as you'd probably want with subclasses!
